# XSL: Extracting value base of content of other elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a complete newbie in XSL... I can't figure out how to get the content of a elements based on the content of a child element.

XML example:

```
<main_caracs>
        <Label/>
        <Value>Essence, Hybride</Value>
    </main_caracs>
    <main_caracs>
        <Label/>
        <Value>Traction avant</Value>
    </main_caracs>
    <main_caracs>
        <Label>Consommation sur route</Label>
        <Value>8,4 litres aux 100 km</Value>
    </main_caracs>
    <main_caracs>
        <Label>Consommation en ville</Label>
        <Value>12,4 litres aux 100 km</Value>
    </main_caracs>
```

I need to extract the text of the /main_caracs/Label/Value but only when the content of the  is "Consommation en ville".

I try various thing with choose, etc... but not luck. If someone can give me some hints It will be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a root element in your XML. I just called it x:

```
<x>
<main_caracs>
        <Label/>
        <Value>Essence, Hybride</Value>
    </main_caracs>
    <main_caracs>
        <Label/>
        <Value>Traction avant</Value>
    </main_caracs>
    <main_caracs>
        <Label>Consommation sur route</Label>
        <Value>8,4 litres aux 100 km</Value>
    </main_caracs>
    <main_caracs>
        <Label>Consommation en ville</Label>
        <Value>12,4 litres aux 100 km</Value>
    </main_caracs>
</x>
```

Then transform with this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
<!-- get the Value of the main_caracs that has a Label that = 'Consommation en ville' -->
        <xsl:value-of select="x/main_caracs[Label='Consommation en ville']/Value" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So this part [Label='Consommation en ville'] is looking inside the <Label> for the "Consommation en ville" text? 

I was close... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, conditions that apply at that point in the xpath can be placed in [].